# Remove 'disabled' of an element which is present in a redirected page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I'm redirecting users from a.html to `b.html` page after login. There is a file select button "`Select Images`" with "`disabled`" attribute on `b.html` page, which I want to be enabled only after FB login. Below is my code for this.

```
function fblogin(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            login();            
        } else {                
            //window.location.reload();
        }
    }, {scope:'email,publish_stream'});
    return false;
}
function login() {
    window.location = "b.html";             
    document.getElementById('uploadbtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
    document.getElementById("genPNG").attr('disabled','enabled');    
    document.getElementById("genJPG").removeAttribute('disabled');       
}
```

No luck with the above code, so I putted

```
document.getElementById('uploadbtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById("genPNG").attr('disabled','enabled');    
document.getElementById("genJPG").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

on `b.html` page.  How can I make it work as the way I want? Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `.prop('disabled', false)` or `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: From the code aboe the function login() function changes the page to b.html. That would tell me that your remove attribute code should be in b.html not the page that directs it to b.html.

Comment: if you're redirecting to b.html why don't you just keep the fields enabled in b.html by default? Why do you want to remove it from your javascript?

Comment: @ArvindSridharan
Because, I want those features to be enabled only after login. Its a pure HTML5 page, is there any other way to accomplish that?

Comment: @PrateekSaini - you could set a cookie in page A and read that cookie in page B. If the cookie is set, you can then enable the elements. you can use the jquery cookie plugin to do this.

Comment: If the user is logged in with facebook on page A, that user will also be logged in on page B, so just add a script that checks the login status and sets the disabled property accordingly

Comment: @adeneo - yes, this is a better way. didn't think of the facebook utility there.

Comment: @adeneo
Page A is login page and I'm redirecting on b.html. I think jQuery cookie plugin mentioned by ArvindSridharan will work out. Any comment on this?

Comment: Cookies will probably work, but it just seems so much easier to just call `FB.getLoginStatus` and actually check that the user is logged in? Note that changing the disabled property is just a matter of opening the console and changing it, something any five year old can do, so this is in no way secure ?

Comment: @adeneo
Yeah that's what I was thinking. Any user can directly open my b.html page with URL and if I put the .prop() function on that page, it will enable all features. Any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery methods on plain JS DOM nodes (however removeAttribute should work?), it should be :

```
$('#uploadbtn').prop('disabled', false);
```

Note that this has to be added in **b.html**, as once you've left the page, it's a bit late for javascript, it does nothing on the next page ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop('disabled', false)` or `.prop('disabled', true)`

From the jQuery `.prop()` (setter) [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value):

> The .prop() method is a convenient way to set the value of
>   properties—especially when setting multiple properties, using values
>   returned by a function, or setting values on multiple elements at
>   once. It should be used when setting `selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName,`
>   `nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked,` or `defaultSelected`. Since
>   jQuery 1.6, these properties can no longer be set with the .attr()
>   method. They do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties.
>
> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting
>   value.

Comment: this is a very generic answer. please answer the question specifically and then refer to general documentation.

Comment: Pull your head out, I answered more completely than you did.